# How can I copy a string into another string char by char in AT&T Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

I'm very new to assembly so forgive me if I use incorrect terms. I am trying to create my own printf in assembly. I've started off with looping through `text` char by char and checking to see if there is a percent sign. Once it detects it, the code moves on to an if statement checking if the char next to it is an `s`, `u`, `%`, or `d`. However, while it's checking each char, I want it to copy each char into the string variable I created called `finalStr`. My attempt to do this is in the `DIYprintf` function.

Sorry about how sloppy the code is, me and my partner are in the middle of testing everything so it's a little all over the place. Any help is appreciated !

```
.text

    argPercent: .asciz "%"
    percentEnd: .equ lengthPercent, percentEnd - argPercent

    argString: .asciz "Michael and Leonidas"
    stringEnd: .equ lengthString, text

    text: .asciz "Our names are: %s and %%"
    textend: .equ lengthText, textend - text

    finalStr: .asciz ""
    strEnd: .equ lengthStr, 200

    formatspecifier: .asciz "%"

    formatstring: .asciz "s"
    formatint:  .asciz "d"
    formatunint: .asciz "u"
    formatpercent: .asciz "%"


.global main                   

main:
    pushq %rbp          
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    call DIYprintf

    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp

    end:
    movq $60, %rax
    movq $0, %rdx
    syscall

DIYprintf:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    leaq (text), %rsi
    leaq (formatspecifier), %rdi
    leaq (finalStr), %r12

    movq $lengthText, %r10

    loop: 
    cmpsb 
    je equal

    decq %r10
    cmpq $0, %r10
    je endLoop

    movq %rsi, %r12

    incq %rsi
    incq %r12
    jmp loop

    endLoop:
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    ret


equal:
    incq %rsi

    cmpsb
    je string

    #cmpsb
    #je integer

    #cmpsb
    #je uninteger

   # cmpsb
    #je percent

    jmp loop

#percent:

string:
call end
```

Comment: For starters,  `.asciz ""` only allocates a single zero byte. Certainly no space for your string. Using `cmps` to  compare a single character is overkill. Copying char by char is as simple as loading a char and writing it out, incrementing the pointers. What's causing you problem with that?

Comment: @Jester Would I have to remove the quotation marks then? And I'm trying to do that with `leaq (finalStr), %r12` and `movq %rsi, %r12 incq %rsi incq %r12`. Thank you for the cmp tip!

Comment: To allocate space you can use e.g. the [`.fill` directive](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Fill.html). Not sure what you wanted `movq %rsi, %r12` to do, but it doesn't make any sense to me.  You'd pick a byte register and read-write that, e.g. `movb (%rsi), %al` and `movb %al, (%r12)`. You can then do your comparisons against `%al`.

Comment: That looks okay, although you don't need the `()` but those are harmless. Your problem is you put your data into the `.text` section which is read only. Switch to `.data` but don't forget to switch back for your code.

Comment: @Jester You're a legend. Thank you so much.